# Given a right triangle $ABC$, with right angle at $C$ and side lengths...

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

**Problem:** Given a right triangle $ABC$, with right angle at $C$ and side lengths $|AB|=c \ , |BC|=a$ and $|CA|=b,$ let $r$ denote the radius of the inscribed circle. Then it is true that:

a) $r=\dfrac{a+b-c}{2}$

b) $r=\dfrac{c-a-b}{2}$

c) $r=\dfrac{3a+2b-2c}{2}$

d) $r=\dfrac{2c-a-b}{2}$

This is a problem that one should be able to solve by eliminating the wrong answers without doing too much arithmetic and memorising different formulas. What is the most effective way of eliminating the wrong answers? I drew a picture of the problem but I can't really see how to relate $r$ to the sides of the triangle.

I'd also know how to rigorously prove the correct answer, but this is just a curios sidestep.

Comment: Do you mean to have equations as the choices? Right now they are just expressions that don't indicate anything.

Comment: Sorry, will edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The answer should be symmetric in $a,b\,$, which eliminates option **c)**.
- The triangle inequality $c \le a+b$ gives a negative $r$ for option **b)** which eliminates it.
- When one the legs $a \to 0$ the other one $ b \to c\,$, and in that case $r \to 0\,$, which eliminates **d)**.

Or, just use that $\,r = \cfrac{ab}{a+b+c}\,$ by the right triangle area argument, then easily verify **a)**.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetric" and how does it eliminate c)? I understood point 2 and 3, excellent explanation!

Comment: @Parseval Thanks. By "symmetric" I meant that right triangles with sides $a,b,c$ and $b,a,c$ are simply reflections of one another, and have the same inradius $r\,$, therefore the expression for $r$ must be invariant when you swap the variables $a,b$. But **c)** is not symmetric in $a,b\,$, since $3a + 2b \ne 3b + 2a$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using the [relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumradius.html) of in & circum-radius,

$$r=R(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C-1)=R(\sin B+\sin A-\sin C)$$ as $C=90^\circ,\sin C,\cos C=?$

Now use Sine Law

Comment: Should be able to solve this without having to memorize that relation. But thanks, this answers my second curiosity question!

Comment: @Parseval, I think we need to memorize some relations like https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t121f6h1342529s1_relationship_between_inradius_circumradius_and_sides

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trigonograph from [an answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2247686/409):

[image]

$$( a - r ) + ( b - r ) = 2 R$$

(where $R$ is the circumradius). For your question, we can ignore the circumcircle and replace the right-hand side of the relation with $c$.

Answer (score 1):

There are very useful known identities for a general triangles
that bind area $S$, semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
inradius $r$
and corresponding angles $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$:

\begin{align}
S&=\rho\,r,
\\
S&=
\rho(\rho-a)\tan\tfrac\alpha2
=
\rho(\rho-b)\tan\tfrac\beta2
=
\rho(\rho-c)\tan\tfrac\gamma2
\end{align}

For the right triangle we have $\tan\tfrac\gamma2=\tan\tfrac\pi4=1$
and $r=\tfrac12(a+b-c)$ instantly follows.