# For $\triangle ABC$ with right angle at $A$ and inradius $r$, show that $2r=b+c-a$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

I am trying to solve this problem:

> The angle $A$ of $\triangle ABC$ is a right angle, and the sides of $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ are of lengths $a$, $b$, and $c$, respectively. Each side of the triangle is tangent to a circle of radius r. Show that $2r=b+c-a$.

I have no idea on how to solve this problem, and could you guys help me with to solve it?

Thank you so much for you guys’ replies.

Comment: what do you mean by " Each side of the triangle to the circle S1 which is of radius r."?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed it, I forgot to type tangent..

Comment: Related (duplicate, when you realize the circumdiameter of a right triangle is its hypotenuse): ["Radii of inscribed and circumscribed circles in right-angled triangle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2247599/409). See, in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2247686/409).

Comment: @Blue Thank you, your proof is so beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $r=(S-a)tan(\frac{A}{2})$
$$ $$
Where $\angle A =90°$ hence
$$r=s-a$$
$$2r=b+c-a$$